# Is string formation optimized by the compiler?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, compiler-construction

I was trying to answer another question about the == operator and I created this code:

```
NSString *aString = @"Hello";
NSString *bString = aString;
NSString *cString = @"Hello";

if (aString == bString)
    NSLog(@"CHECK 1");

if (bString == cString)
    NSLog(@"CHECK 2");

if ([aString isEqual:bString])
    NSLog(@"CHECK 3");

if ([aString isEqual:cString])
    NSLog(@"CHECK 4");

NSLog(@"%i", aString);
NSLog(@"%i", bString);
NSLog(@"%i", cString);
```

But was surprised at the results:

```
Equal[6599:10b] CHECK 1
Equal[6599:10b] CHECK 2
Equal[6599:10b] CHECK 3
Equal[6599:10b] CHECK 4
Equal[6599:10b] 8240
Equal[6599:10b] 8240
Equal[6599:10b] 8240
```

Is there some compiler trickery going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is clearly string uniquing going on, at least within a single compilation unit. I recommend you take a brief tour through `man gcc` during which you visit all uses of "string". You'll find a few options that are directly relevant to literal `NSString`s and their toll-free-bridged counterparts, `CFString`s:

- **`-fconstant-string-class`=*class-name*** sets the name of the class used to instantiate `@"..."` literals. It defaults to `NSConstantString` unless you're using the GNU runtime. (If you don't know if you are, you aren't.)
- **`-fconstant-cfstrings`** enables use of a builtin to create `CFString`s when you write `CFSTR(...)`.

You can disable uniquing for C string literals using `-fwritable-strings`, though this option is deprecated. I couldn't come up with a combination of options that would stop the uniquing of `NSString` literals in an Objective-C file. (Anyone want to speak to Pascal string literals?)

You see `-fconstant-cfstrings` coming into play in `CFString.h`'s definition of the `CFSTR()` macro used to create `CFString` literals:

```
    #ifdef __CONSTANT_CFSTRINGS__
    #define CFSTR(cStr)  ((CFStringRef) __builtin___CFStringMakeConstantString ("" cStr ""))
    #else
    #define CFSTR(cStr)  __CFStringMakeConstantString("" cStr "")
    #endif
```

If you look at the implementation of the non-builtin `__CFStringMakeConstantString()` in [`CFString.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-299.33/String.subproj/CFString.c), you'll see that the function does indeed perform uniquing using a very large `CFMutableDictionary`:

```
    if ((result = (CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(constantStringTable, cStr))) {
        __CFSpinUnlock(&_CFSTRLock);
    }
    // . . .
    return result;
```

See also responses to the question, ["What's the difference between a string constant and a string literal?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-constant-and-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 4):

NSString is defined as an immutable type, so whenever the compiler can optimize things by combining identical strings, it should. As your code demonstrates, gcc clearly does perform this optimization for simple cases.

Comment: This is correct.  The internal type of the string is actually an NSConstantString, and it cannot be released. It is made static by the compiler apparently overrides its -release method to no-op.

Answer (score 2):

Well for cString and aString, C,C++, and Objective C compilers can reuse a compile time string object if it is declared in more than one location.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simple copy-on-write optimization? As all 3 strings point to the same 'set of characters' there's not point in creating separate copies until you modify one of the strings.

Probably the characters are stored in static part of memory (with the code) and NSStrings* point to that part of memory. Once you attempt to modify one of the strings it will create new string somewhere else (heap) and then reference that memory.

Comment: True, I was thinking more conceptually ... anyway seems like they all point to the same part of memory because they represent the same group of characters ...