# Defining String Literals?

Tags: memory, nsstring, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a string constant and a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-constant-and-a-string-literal)

Can anyone confirm this for me ...

```
NSString *testString = @"Betty";
```

By my way of thinking this line is declaring the NSString pointer (*testString) to point to the string literal @"Betty". This declaration does not need an alloc, nor does it need to be released? I just want to make sure I am on the right track.

-gary-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. The string literal will be compiled to a immutable instance of `NSString`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-constant-and-a-string-literal) for more details.