# What is the difference between a String Constant and String Literal in C?

Tags: c, string-literals, string-constant

What's the difference between a **String Constant** and **String Literal** in plain C?

*This question is similar to another: [What's the difference between a string constant and a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-constant-and-a-string-literal) ...except that one was regarding Objective-C (using NSString) and not C.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are one and the same. Merely a preference in which word you use to describe the string.

Comment: You mean which *string* is used to describe the string :)

Comment: Not all constants are literals.

Answer (score 7):

In the [C99 Draft from 2007](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.open-std.org%2Fjtc1%2Fsc22%2FWG14%2Fwww%2Fdocs%2Fn1256.pdf&rct=j&q=C99%20language%20specification%20draft&ei=19WzTM6ODoHUtQPx_vGKCA&usg=AFQjCNHU9huO6pbDQC2pyO-ujAa8WohaKw&sig2=i3rPNWKYmEb1Nic4bqGLLA&cad=rja) the term *sting literal* is used. The term *string constant* does not appear in the draft at all.

I find *string literal* to be a good term choice when talking about "foo" (just as 42 is a literal number, "foo" is a literal string).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. :)  What confused me was that many books use the term String Constant, but C99 uses String Literal as you said.

Answer (score 1):

The spelling of the second word used to describe the same idea?

I would regard them as the same thing - alternative terms for the same construct.

Comment: So basically, either the phrase String Literal or String Constant can be used to mean the same thing?

Comment: @Dave: Yes, that's what I said (slightly caveated) - and what other people said too.

Comment: As noted by @BenVoigt in other comments, a literal is a constant, but a constant may not be a literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char * strConst;
strConst = "Hello World";
```

In this example

- `strConst` is a string constant.
- `"Hello World"` is a string literal, and is typically stored in the read only area of the program.

Comment: Interesting analysis, but it doesn't really stand up, I'm afraid.  The variable `strConst` is, indeed, a variable; it may be changed to point to other strings than the string literal, but you will not be able to modify the string pointed at via `strConst`.  If you had written `const char * const strConst = "Hello World";`, then you might have a stronger case, but `strConst` is still a pointer rather than a string constant; a constant pointer to a constant string, but still a pointer, not a string constant.

Comment: Point was that literals are actual text not hidden via a varible label.  But they are both constant character arrays.

Answer (score 0):

*Literal* and *constant* mean the same which is notation for representing a fixed value in source code.

Comment: Not true.  `sizeof (int)` is a constant, but it is not a literal.