# Can't manipulate a string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *string = @"HELLO";
```

For some reason, XCode won't auto-complete methods like remove characters or append etc... If that's the case, how can I, say, remove certain characters from my string? Say I want to remove all the L's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSString` doesn't respond to those methods. `NSMutableString` does, but you've declared an immutable string variable and assigned to it a string literal. Since an Objective-C `@"string literal"` is always immutable (an instance of `NSString` but not `NSMutableString`), there's no way those messages can be sent to the object you're using.

If you want a mutable string, try:

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = [[@"HELLO" mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an immutable string literal.

Here is a great post explaining it in further details:

[What's the difference between a string constant and a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-constant-and-a-string-literal)

As for your question on how would you change it and remove the Ls:

```
NSString *hello = @"HELLO";
NSString *subString = [hello stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"L" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"subString: %@", subString);
```

That outputs "HEO"

Either that or you can create an NSMutableString by creating a copy of the mutable string like Jonathan mentioned.  In both examples, you're copying it into a non-literal string.