# Scope of static NSString?

Tags: static, nsstring, scope, ios5

I am trying to declare a constant string in a method frequently called and at the start of the method I have used:

```
static NSString *kAPICall       = @"Mail Messages";
```

Is the correct way, most efficient to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean constant or static?

Comment: You hit the nail on the head ..... I need a constant value for the life of the method, but not really sure of which / how to use? Basic I know!

Comment: Please read these two questions and their answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-constant-and-a-string-literal