# In Objective C(w/ ARC), why do not dealloc a weak reference if it once used?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

here is code

```
@interface Test : NSObject {
    int val;
}

-(int) GetOne;
@end

@implementation Test
-(int) GetOne {
    return 1;
} 
@end
```

and use Test class like this

```
Test * a = [Test new];
Test * __weak b = a;

[b GetOne];
a = nil;

printf("a=%p, b=%p\n", a, b);
```

the result is b is not 0.
why does this happen?

Comment: maybe it lives in the autorelease pool

Comment: if I remove "[b GetOne];", then the result is b is 0.
"GetOne function call" push b to the autorelease pool?

Comment: You should format your question to be more readable

Comment: thats very likely. because you don't want b deallocated while `[b GetOne]` is executing. try `@autoreleasepool{[b GetOne];}`

Comment: I swear I saw almost this exact question yesterday

Comment: Not the one from yesterday, but: [strong and weak for local variable, I dont understand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922888/strong-and-weak-for-local-variable-i-dont-understand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARC will generate a jungle of memory management calls and then optimize away what it determines aren't needed. It's a very different process from the manual memory management of old. I make no claims about understanding how the compiler works in that regard, and that's the beauty of it; you don't have to understand.

Think of ARC as a magic black box that makes one promise: if you follow the rules, it will automatically clean up after you *eventually*. It may not be at the very earliest moment possible, but it will happen.

I've assumed you're using LLVM 4.2 (ships with Xcode 4.6), and I tested it out. The object does indeed end up in an autorelease pool. This is an example of a case where ARC could do better, because the autorelease isn't actually needed.

Following that thought, I also tried it on the LLVM 5.0 compiler beta, and the behavior is different: the object is immediately deallocated on `a = nil` as you would expect. This is a good example of ARC getting smarter while still keeping the same basic promise.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I use LLVM 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

ARC will help you to release and retain object but.... **what exact time will the object be free**.

You should read about non-ARC and then ARC. There are too many guy on stackoverflow said about it

(you can read this: [ARC - The meaning of __unsafe_unretained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592289/arc-the-meaning-of-unsafe-unretained))