# Weak local variables in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, weak-references, local-variables

I am new to Objective-C and I would like to ask a question about declaring a local variable (and non-property instance variable) as _weak. Is it a good practice to do so in order to avoid memory leak?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strong and weak for local variable, I don't understand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922888/strong-and-weak-for-local-variable-i-dont-understand)

Comment: If you are new to Obj-C I wouldn't recommend declaring any local variables as weak, unless you need to to use them inside a block, (Xcode will complain and make this obvious)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have already read that thread but I was just wondering if it is something common to write local variables with _weak.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak or problems can occur if you use strong references inside blocks for example. It is better to search on SO before post questions. You should also read here a very nice explain:  [Differences between strong and weak in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013587/differences-between-strong-and-weak-in-objective-c)

If you want to access self method, for example, inside a block, you can define as:

```
   __block id WeakSelf = self;
```

then inside your block you can call as:

```
   {  // -> inside block
   [WeakSelf dosomeFunction];
   } // <-  block ends
```

Comment: the memory leaks are not localized only for blocks, there are many other ways of how an application can define a strong reference cycle.

Comment: I know, I just give user an example.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have already read that thread but I was just wondering if it is something common to write local variables with _weak.