# Assigning object to weak reference in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, nsobject

According to `ARC` in `iOS`, an object must have at least one `strong` reference to stay in memory, when there is no `strong` reference (**ie. reference count becomes 0**), the object will be deallocated from memory and we will have no longer access to the object.

But I am getting strange behavior in my code.

I am assigning to `weak` reference `NSString` in code,
when I write `[[NSString alloc] init];`  Xcode give warning .

```
__weak NSString *str;
str = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

> Assigning retained object to weak property; object will be released after assignment.

[image: Xcode warning screenshot]

if I do like this, Xcode doesn't gives any warning,

```
__weak NSString *str;
str = @"abcd";
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

[image: No Warning Screenshot]

**Output**:
abcd

[image: Output Screenshot]

**My Question is:**

Why it is printing `"abcd"` as output. even if `str` is a *weak* reference variable. Who is keeping this `NSString` object which value is `"abcd"` in memory?

Comment: Objective-C string literals are treated differently. They are constants kept in memory so none of the normal memory management rules apply to them.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922888/weak-nsstring-variable-is-not-nil-after-setting-the-only-strong-reference-to-nil

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, because it's interesting to understand why there's a warning in one case but not the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say `str = @"abcd"`, you're not using a code pattern that the compiler recognizes as returning a newly-allocated object, so you don't trigger the warning about a direct assignment of a new object to a `__weak` variable.

Furthermore, a string literal like `@"abcd"` is stored in your program's executable file. It's never deallocated. The `retain` and `release` operations don't actually change its retain count. Its retain count is set to a magic number indicating an immortal object. So your `__weak` variable `str` doesn't actually get set to nil, because the object it references doesn't get deallocated. That's why it prints `abcd`.

In fact, clang specifically suppresses a warning if you assign a string literal (as opposed to some other kind of literal like an array literal `@[a, b, c]`). See the comment in [the clang source code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Sema/SemaChecking.cpp):

```
static bool checkUnsafeAssignLiteral(Sema &S, SourceLocation Loc,
                                     Expr *RHS, bool isProperty) {
  // Check if RHS is an Objective-C object literal, which also can get
  // immediately zapped in a weak reference.  Note that we explicitly
  // allow ObjCStringLiterals, since those are designed to never really die.
  RHS = RHS->IgnoreParenImpCasts();

  // This enum needs to match with the 'select' in
  // warn_objc_arc_literal_assign (off-by-1).
  Sema::ObjCLiteralKind Kind = S.CheckLiteralKind(RHS);
  if (Kind == Sema::LK_String || Kind == Sema::LK_None)
    return false;

  S.Diag(Loc, diag::warn_arc_literal_assign)
    << (unsigned) Kind
    << (isProperty ? 0 : 1)
    << RHS->getSourceRange();

  return true;
}
```

So if we change the type to `NSArray` and use an array literal, we get a warning:

[image: array literal assignment warning]

Moving on… You get the warning when you say `str = [[NSString alloc] init]` because the compiler recognizes that `[[NSString alloc] init]` is a code pattern that typically returns a new object.

**However**, in the particular case of `[[NSString alloc] init]`, you'll discover that `str` again doesn't get set to nil. That's because `-[NSString init]` is special-cased to return a global empty-string object. It doesn't actually make a new object on each call.

```
    __weak NSString *str;
    str = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%ld %p [%@]", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)str), str, str);
```

Output:

```
2018-01-24 01:00:22.963109-0600 test[3668:166594] 1152921504606846975 0x7fffe55b19c0 []
```

That 1152921504606846975 is the magic retain count indicating an immortal object.

Comment: That means in both cases object will never be deallocated ?

Comment: Yes, in both cases you are setting `str` to an immortal object.

Comment: @robmayoff this would mean, the @"abcd", which itself is an object, will stay in the memory as long as the scope(a class or a method) in which it is defined in. But it will be nullified as soon as its parent gets out of the picture. Or since the retain count is such a big number, it will never go out and keep eating the memory? Because even if the parent gets out it will only decrease the retain count by 1

Answer (score 0):

```
#define TLog(_var) ({ NSString *name = @#_var; NSLog(@"%@: %@ -> %p: %@ retainCount:%ld", name, [_var class], _var, _var, CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)(_var))); })
```

```
__weak NSString *str;
str = @"abcd";
NSLog(@"%@",str
      );
TLog(str);
```

After debug with your code I found that `[str class]` is `NSCFConstantString` and it's retainCount is `1152921504606846975`.

for the retainCount in `Objective-C`, If the object's retainCount equals `1152921504606846975`, it means "unlimited retainCount", this object can not be released though it is assigning to weak reference.

All `__NSCFConstantString` object's retainCount is `1152921504606846975`, which means `__NSCFConstantString` will not be released whether it is *__weak*. The `NSString` created using the `*str = @"abcd";` will be the same object if they are same value whether how many times to be written.

Comment: `1152921504606846975` doesn't really mean "unlimited".  It is an implementation artifact and may change at any time.  In general, `retainCount` is utterly useless.

Comment: No worries.   In general, one should ignore both the class and the allocation type used for an object that is sourced from the frameworks.  Far better to just treat it as a delta'd reference count.  I.e. strong is +1 and when the strong goes out of scope or is nil'd it is -1.  Let the system do its thing and if you need to debug, use the object graph inspector to determine what is holding a strong reference.