# Issue comparing NSString literal and constant

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, nsstring, string-literals

I have an `NSString`, `firstWord`, that has the value of "First". It was defined like this:

```
NSString *firstWord = [[NSString alloc] init];

firstWord = [textView text];
```

However, when I try to check its value, like so:

```
if (firstWord == @"First"){}
```

The comparison does not return true, or YES I guess in Objective-C. I know that it does have the same value as a string. So, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-constant-and-a-string-literal) I am pretty sure that the issue is that I am comparing pointers, which are not the same here, even though the strings themselves do have the same value. So how can I directly compare the strings themselves? Or maybe more efficiently, make sure the two string objects *do* have the same pointer, so I don't have to the do the relatively costly string comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how can I directly compare the strings themselves?

String comparison in Cocoa is done with [`isEqualToString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-isEqualToString_).

> Or maybe more efficiently, make sure the two string objects do have the same pointer,

This isn't possible. One is a string literal, stored in the DATA section of your app's binary; the other is on your app's heap. In certain circumstances (creating a string using `initWithString:@"literal string"`) you'll end up with the same address, but you shouldn't rely on that.

As an aside, you don't need to -- in fact, shouldn't, because you're creating a leak -- allocate a string before assigning the text view's text to the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two errors.

Your actual question:

```
if (firstWord == @"First"){}
```

needs to be

```
if ([firstword compare:@"first"]==NSOrderedSame) ...
```

Only works if firstword isn't nil.

In addition:

```
NSString *firstWord = [[NSString alloc] init];
firstWord = [textView text];
```

This looses memory, since you are not "copying" the textview into the string (which wouldn't be possible anyway since it's not mutable), you are simply assigning another string object to the pointer. So the empty string that you've allocated is lost.

Just do

```
NSString *firstWord;
firstWord = [textView text];
```

EDIT: making sure the strings have the same pointers would be even more costly, since you would have to keep a table of string objects and lookup every string there so you can either replace your pointer with the "unique" one or add the new string to the table...

Comment: Actually, if `firstWord` is `nil`, the expression will be true, because the message will evaluate to 0, which is the same value as `NSOrderedSame`.

Comment: Which is usually not what you want; in most cases, a nil string will be considered "not equal" to some real string by the developer

Comment: Right; so you'll have a `nil` string that seems to be equal to some non-`nil` string. Thus, use `isEqualToString:`.

Answer (score -1):

Start to learn Objective-C from Swift. Here is what I do to give different layout code per deviceModel type.

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *deviceModel;

    NSString *iPhoneSE = @"iPhone8,4";
    if ([self.deviceModel isEqualToString:iPhoneSE]) { // iPhone SE
        // layout code
    }
```

Comment: `isEqualToString` has already been mentioned in the accepted answer.